# Easier method to group by multiple newlines

Tags: c#, string, linq

Today I've faced a problem that looked easy at glance but it was not certainly as simple. My task is to group multiple strings separated by two newlines. Example:

```
a
b

c
d

e
f
g

h
```

into:

```
[ [a, b], [c, d], [e, f, g], [h] ]
```

At first I thought about getting the groups out of a regular expression, but I couldn't find the right one to separate and give me the strings grouped. Then I decided to look at it with LINQ, but I couldn't manage to get anything useful either. Any tips?

Comment: show the code so we can help with specific issues and a first version approach could be something as simple as,  print "[" + "[" + $input + "]" ... + "]" .

Comment: what about using `String.Split()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.Split` with two concatenated `Environment.NewLine`:

```
string[][] result = text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(token => token.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NinneE

Answer (score 2):

Splitting input by new line is a classic from AOC.
Here is a part of my extention Method .net 7:

```
public static class Extention{
  /// <summary>
  /// Splits a text into lines.
  /// </summary>
  public static IEnumerable<string> Lines(this string text) => text.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  /// <summary>
  /// Splits a text into blocks of lines. Split occurs on each empty line.
  /// </summary>
  public static IEnumerable<string> Blocks(this string text) => text.Trim().Split(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Code will be :

```
var result = text.Blocks()
                 .Select(b => b.Lines());
```

NB:
`.Split(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine,` is .NET 7

Comment: elegant answer, ty!

Comment: It's the same as the other answer. But with extention it make answers more readable. Commonly used in online coding challenge like https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1. EG the answer of that particular exercice will be `text.Blocks().Max(b=> b.Lines().Select(int.Parse).Sum())`